# Pandas groupby().apply works inconsistently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a function for processing Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```py
def do_things(df: pd.DataFrame):
  cols = ["A","B","C"]
  return (
    df.groupby(cols, observed=True)
      .apply(fn)
      .reset_index(level=cols)
  )
```

It either works perfectly, *or* it spits out `ValueError: cannot insert C, already exists`. The exception seems to come from calling `reset_index` on an empty df. The confusing part is that I've added print statements before the call to check the inputs, and within `fn` to check if it's called. Watching those prints, the inputs don't matter; reruns on identical inputs will sometimes fail and sometimes not. The difference I can find is that sometimes `fn` just isn't called, leading to failure, causing an empty df to be fed into `reset_index` and leading to error.

Why is `apply` inconsistently calling `fn` regardless of input? How do I get it to behave? This feels like some under-the-hood optimization or lazy execution is screwing things up, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

### Side Notes

- `fn` just returns a dataframe of summary stats and confidence intervals.
- The script calling this function processes many dataframes. When it's successful, the whole batch succeeds. When it's not, all fail. Again, the specific inputs are irrelevant, since the same ones will fail/succeed on rerun.
- Reruns always pull a new local copy of the data and creates a uniquified output directory (i.e. they're independent of each other).
- The full version of this runs in a docker container to keep everything (deps, env, etc) consistent, so I've eliminated those as problems. The output is inconsistent regardless of it being run in a container vs locally.
- Breaking the call up into separate pieces (i.e. `x = df.groupby(...)`, `y = x.apply(...)`, etc) causes `apply` to consistently return an empty df without calling `fn` and culminates in the `ValueError` above. This is what leads me to believe some sort of optimization is screwing things up.

### EDIT

Roughly, `fn` looks like this (there's about a dozen other summary stats in there, but you get the idea).

```py
def fn(grp):
  """Assumes column X exists"""
  return pd.DataFrame({
    "mean": [grp["X"].mean()],
    "sd": [grp["X"].std()],
    "median": [grp["X"].median()],
  })
```

### EDIT 2

This is basically `df`:

```
   A                  B        C           X
0  experiment_label1  sample1  treatment1  70.23412
1  experiment_label1  sample1  treatment2  23.12314
2  experiment_label1  sample2  treatment1  53.54321
3  experiment_label1  sample2  treatment2  65.74329
4  experiment_label2  sample1  treatment1  46.37284
5  experiment_label2  sample1  treatment2  54.37821
6  experiment_label2  sample2  treatment1  90.74383
7  experiment_label2  sample2  treatment2  89.65424
```

As mentioned in the comments, the real ones are 10's of thousands of rows. They're also 20 columns, but the additional cols are just the various treatment categoricals. Everything except `X` is included in the groupby.

Worth mentioning, comment wisdom was able to divine that the specific exception being thrown comes from `fn` never being called, so pandas has to infer the columns, and reuses the original ones, resulting in collision. Still unsure *why* `fn` isn't being called.

Comment: Please add `fn` and a sample of your dataframe to the question. We can't reproduce your error otherwise

Comment: And please also include a sample `df` that causes the error

Comment: I'm working on trying to make one that can fit in here. The smallest working one I have is 72000 rows and is full of proprietary data.

Comment: The error you're getting doesn't really match your description. Plainly, the error is telling you your aggregation results in a column labeled `'C'`, but because you also groupy `'C'` that label also exists in the index. Thus, when you try to `reset_index` there is a collision where pandas sees a column already has the label you are trying to insert, hence the error.

Comment: That is, just remove the `.reset_index(...)` and look at the resulting DataFrame. You _should_ see both a column labeled `'C'` and an index level with the name `'C'` -- you need to fix this, likely by renaming one of the columns in your aggregation result

Comment: @ALollz you just made me realize why the empty df is key. `fn` returns a different set of columns. If `apply` doesn't call `fn`, then pandas has to infer the columns, and (incorrectly) reuses the ones from the input, resulting in collision.

Comment: Do you mind to add the expected output?

Comment: While you try to produce a [mcve] do you mind to test `df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])["X"].agg({"mean", "std", "median"}).reset_index()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat unsatisfying answer. One of the variables is the region, which includes a value "NA". It's intended to represent "North America", but Pandas was "helpfully" interpreting it as a null value, which caused havoc. Changing the upstream `read_csv`'s `na_values` solves the issue.

I still don't know why it worked sometimes and others not, or why `compare` between the dfs supplied to successful vs failed runs came back empty, but at least it's fixed.